# Compact support vs. vanishing at infinity?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the two sets

$$ C_0 = \{ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C \mid f \text{ is continuous and } \lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x) = 0\}$$

$$ C_c = \{ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C \mid f \text{ is continuous and }  \operatorname{supp}{(f)} \text{ is bounded}\}$$

> Aren't these two sets the same? What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that $C_c \subset C_0$, but $C_c \neq C_0$. For example, $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$ belongs to $C_0$ but not $C_c$.

What you seem to be assuming is that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x) = 0$ implies that there is some $N > 0$ with $f(x) = 0$ for all $|x| > N$. This is not true, as the above example demonstrates. That is, a function can limit to zero at $\pm\infty$ without ever being zero.

Answer (score 1):

The first one contains functions which are nonzero over the whole real line. The second one does not.

Answer (score 0):

Another example would be $f : x \mapsto e^{-|x|},$ $x \in \mathbb R.$ Then $f \in C_0 (\mathbb R)$ but $f \notin C_c (\mathbb R).$